# Is 胡 missplaced in the Kodansha Kanji Learner's Dictionary?

Tags: kanji, dictionary, stroke-count

I recently tried to look up the kanji `胡` in the [Kodansha Kanji Learner's Dictionary](http://www.kanji.org/kanji/dictionaries/learners/learners.htm), which uses the SKIP method to look up each kanji, and I couldn't find it. It seemed to me a relatively straightforward kanji look-up using the SKIP method: It is clearly divided side-to-side (making the first digit '1'), and the number of strokes for the left hand side is 5 and the number for the right hand side is 4 (giving it a SKIP number 1-5-4). I tried every trick I know to find it and eventually did...under the wrong classification. The '4' and '5' have been reversed so that it is 1-4-5.

It's hard for me to think that this dictionary could be wrong, but I've counted the strokes so many times I don't see where I could be mistaken. I've searched around so see if any else has had the same trouble, but I can't find anyone. Does anyone know why it's been placed where it has? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm... http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E6%95%85 故 is listed as 1-5-4 in jisho, but http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E8%83%A1 胡 is 1-4-5.

Comment: Would you find it surprising if a book with a couple thousand characters in it had one single error in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this is the first time I've heard of SKIP. But according to this [wiki article](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Kodansha_Kanji_Learner%27s_Dictionary), I think it is a mistake.

古 has 5 strokes and 月 has 4, so the SKIP for 胡 should be 1-5-4.

The stroke order listed in [the link](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E8%83%A1) given by jkerian in the comment can also confirm this.

Comment: That seems to be the consensus, I just wanted to ask around to see if I was missing something. Thanks Fefe :)